# defer: usage in case of long running functions?

Tags: go

Here is a sample function that takes a connection to the database from the connection pool and does a query and processes the result returned.

```
func dbQuery() error {
    con := db.getConn()
    result, err := con.Query()
    if err != nil {
       return err
    }
    defer con.close() // or con.close()
    // Processing the result takes a long time


    return nil
}
```

Processing the result in this case takes a long time and close is not called for the connection, which means it is not returned to the connection pool.
 Is it ok to directly call con.close() in cases like this when we know the resources are held for a long time even when they are not needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to refactor your code. This way a `defer` closes the connection **before** you process the result:

```
func dbQuery() error {
    result, err := getResult()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Processing the result takes a long time

    return nil
}

func getResult() (*Rows, error) {
    con := db.getConn()
    defer con.close() // or con.close()

    result, err := con.Query()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return result, err
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In most cases `Close()` methods are idempotent and can be called more than once safely. You `defer con.Close()` in case of an error and/or early function return, but you are perfectly fine to explicitly call `Close()` as soon as you are done with it. So yes, it is best practice to use both when you have some long function.

Comment: Would it make sense to have a return statement like `return con.Close()` when an error maybe returned by Close()? 
defer con.Close() would not allow any sort of error handling right.

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Well, from your question, I would assume you would be done with the connection sometime before your long function finishes, at which point you would want to close the connection and release it to the pool. Given this assumption, wouldn't you rather just capture the err and test it like normal before continuing the function and only return if an error actually exists?

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande: You *can* return values from `defer` by using named return parameters and setting them in the defer function.